# What are the non-isomorphic abelian groups of order 1764?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to find the non-isomorphic abelian groups of order 1764. I have found that 1764 = 2^2 x 3^2 x 7^2.

I followed this question [Computing the number of nonisomorphic finite abelian groups of order $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201690/computing-the-number-of-nonisomorphic-finite-abelian-groups-of-order-n) and then saw that there is 1 partition of 2, thus 1x1x1=1 non-isomorphic abelian group of order 1764.

Is this correct? I have to actually find the group with order 1764 but I'm not sure how to do that, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are $2$ partitions of $2$ – $2$ and $1+1$ – and we can do this for each prime power to get $8$ non-isomorphic groups:
$$4×9×49=1764$$
$$2×2×9×49=2×882$$
$$4×3×3×49=3×588$$
$$4×9×7×7=7×252$$
$$2×2×3×3×49=6×294$$
$$2×2×9×7×7=14×126$$
$$4×3×3×7×7=21×84$$
$$2×2×3×3×7×7=42^2$$